# First-ever vs First

Tags: grammar

Suppose, a football club is formed in the city for the first time of its history. What should I write?

''XYZ is the first club of the city.''

or

''XYZ is the first-ever club of the city.''

Answer (score -1):

I believe that 'XYZ is the first club of (or in) the city' is better. This is because first-ever is redundant, with ever being an unnecessary word as first already implies that it is the first ever (in history) football club in that city.

Comment: "The first club in the city" could mean that it is the largest or most important, so it would be better to say "the first club _to be formed_ in the city". (Or _founded_ or _set up_.)